# Ordering in ggplot2 [plotting pvals by BP for each chr]

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot points along the genome:  there will be plot points for every chromosome.  My data file looks like this:

```
CHROM   BP      P           DP
1      234567   0.0000555   30
.....
Y      12345678 0.09        14
```

I'm using gglopt2 to plot P values, coloured by DP, for each chromosome, using the following:

```
mc.points <- ggplot(sample,aes(x = BP,y = P, colour =DP)) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "Chromosome",y = "P") +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "green", high = "red")
```

However, instead of being plotted at each BP in the right chromosomal order, its being plotted by BP without any thought of chromosome number.

Is there a way to sort the data to make this happen (ie order by chromosome then BP)?  I've tried to make CHROM and BP factors but this seems to crash R.  In addition, if this is possible is there a way to label the X-tics on the X axis as chromosome numbers rather than BP (similar to a Manhattan plot).

I can provide dummy data if need be but this is quite long.

**Just to provide an update:** facet_grid seems to solve my problem but I was wondering whether I can transform this?  It splits the grids by chromosome, but doesn't plot them on the same x-axis in consecutive order - But plots 22 different plots using the same scale x-axis.  Any solutions?????

Comment: You're asking the question of:  `“How do I re-arrange/re-order (plotting geom/aesthetic such as bar/labels) in a (insert plot type here) using(insert graphics system here) in R?”` so see: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and check it.  Though this is probably/is a duplicate question.

Comment: Haven't really answered my question yet = facet_grid seems to be my solution but I need to reverse it somehow - don't want to stack all my chromosomes on top of each other, but plotted on the same axis, in consecutive order.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something this untested code before the plot:

```
sample$BP <- factor(sample$BP, 
                    levels=sample[ !duplicated(sample[,"BP"]), "BP"][
                              order(sample[!duplicated(sample[ ,"BP"]),  "chromosome"] )]
                    )
```

Would have been easier and perhaps more compact if you included a suitable sample for testing. In the future you should NOT use the name `sample" since it is an important R function name.